# Should JavaScript/CSS be put in the bottom of an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile, and for now, I have the following at the bottom of my `<head>` tag:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>help</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Since the user may have a very bad network access, I hope the user can load my page faster, even though the JavaScript or CSS is not ready.

Will it work if I:

1. Put the `<head>` after `<body>`
2. Put the `<script>` in the end of `<body>`

Comment: Developers put `<script>` tags at the bottom of their `<body>` because it allows the whole page to load before the scripts are then fetched. If they are in the `<head>` the user would need to wait for the scripts to be downloaded before the rest of the page is downloaded. I don't think you would want to put the CSS at the bottom of the page, as the user may see unstyled content and then a sudden change when the CSS is loaded. Keep your `<head>` at the top of the document.

Comment: Don't put `<head>` after `<body>`, that's definitely invalid.

Comment: However, once the user has loaded the scripts and CSS files once, they should be cached by the browser and wont need to be downloaded every page visit.

Comment: Hi @BenGuest , for my case, I don't even care if the CSS is loaded because my html is really easy and full of words(this is something like a guide). The main problem is the loading speed, the jquery CSS is just let it a bit beautiful. So, any way to maximize the speed can be considered? Do you have any idea how I can even do not let the CSS block my page loading?

Comment: I guess you could decide which CSS files are really necessary and which are less important, and then place the less important ones at the bottom of the `<body>`.

Comment: @BenGuest, but when i add  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"> in the bottom of the body, ecplise gives me the yellow warnning.

Comment: It is putting the yellow warning there because it isn't best practice to put links to external CSS at the bottom of the `<body>`, but in your specific case, it doesn't sound like it will be a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. No you cannot put the `head` after the `body`.
2. Yes you can, and that is the recommended way because then the browser loads the html components first like you are saying and applies your script afterwards. But you can place it just before you need it and no sooner really. [Read more here](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom).

The css on the other hand should be linked inside your `head` tag.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.For my case, I don't even care if the CSS is loaded because my html is really easy and full of words(this is something like a guide). The main problem is the loading speed, the jquery CSS is just let it a bit beautiful. So, any way to maximize the speed can be considered.Do you have any idea how I can even do not let the CSS block my page loading?

Comment: If you don't have any images or any other heavy stuff loaded in the css, then it isn't particularly resource consuming. I suggest you should examine your css and script content or maybe post it in a new question. Then we can see what could be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put `<head>` after `<body>`.

Putting the `<script>` in the end of `<body>` is good. but, the best solution for your problem is putting `<script>` in the `<head>` tag and use the `async` or `defer` attributes. Explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup).

And CSS should go to `<head>` always.